# Using site CSS with PHP contact form

Tags: php, css

This is my problem. I made my portfolio using the same setup as css zen garden. It has only  4 html pages but it has 4 different CSS layouts it can switch between. I installed a contact form using PHP into the contact page. **How do I make it so my php contact form uses the same CSS the site is currently using at that moment.**

I really need help I cant figure this out.

**My Portfolio:**
[Contact Form](http://www.gzstudios.com/contact.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Working for me... have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: Yeah the site works but I want the contact form to share the current CSS the rest of the page is using.

Comment: Michal is right. You are using an iframe. The css must be tied in to the iframes source and not the current contact form you provided a link for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the CSS in the [iFrame source](http://www.gzstudios.com/contact/contactform.php) too. iFrames do not inherit CSS from their parent page, so basically what you have in the iFrame window is blank HTML with no CSS.

You can make the `contactform.php` use different CSS styles with a $_GET switch (I am sure you know that).

Comment: Okay I guess ill try this with a while loop or something.